# Function question, angular typescript, match id values from 2 arrays to get the index from one of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, indexing

I have a two arrays, and I want to match their ID values and then get the index of that id in the second array. I know this sounds simple but I'm super new to the syntax, and I'm having a hard time picturing what this should look like. can anyone model that in simple terms?

example functionality:

```
var array1 = { id:2, name: 'preston'}

array2 = {
{
   id: 1
   name: 'john'
},
{
   id: 2
   name: 'bob'
}
```

Expected behavior

where both ids = 2, give index of array2.
returns 1

can anyone show me?

Comment: What would the inputs to your function be? Two arrays and the id you are looking for in them?

Comment: Those are not arrays. [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) have brackets `[]` and contain list of objects or primitive values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`findIndex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) on `array2`

Try this:

```js
var array1 = {
  id: 2,
  name: 'preston'
}

var array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'john'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bob'
  }
]

console.log(array2.findIndex(item => item.id === array1.id))
```

Or use [**`indexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you want support for IE as well without polyfills.

```js
var array1 = {
  id: 2,
  name: 'preston'
}

var array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'john'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bob'
  }
]

console.log(array2.map(item => item.id).indexOf(array1.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each item in `array1` using [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Find each item's index in `array2` using [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
var array1 = [{id:2, name: "preston"}];
var array2 = [{id: 1, name: "john" }, {id: 2, name: "bob" }];

array1.forEach(item => {
  let index = array2.findIndex(obj => obj.id === item.id);  
  console.log(index);
});
```